Histograms: discrete data points
I would like some clarification on histograms as I am getting conflicting information.
Question 1
Can histograms be used for discrete data?
I found many sources say that its only used for continuous here, various other text books.
I believe this is incorrect because we can, so why so many sources say that we can't?
Then next question:
Suppose I roll a die 10 times:

I have seen this displayed in 3 different ways(I put the grouped frequency table to what appears the histogram is using)

Example A (source 1, Source 2)
Example B (source: IGCSE maths textbook, source 2)
Example C (Source 1, Source 2)
Ok, so first, are all three pictures correct?
From the first 2 pictures its makes sense, as all we need to do is just make sure the intervals of the grouped frequency table fits in the 'bins' interval of the histogram.
For picture C, if that is the interval given on the histogram, then there would be gaps 2<x<3 and 4<x<5 making it not a histogram, thus from this I must assume that these "intervals" on this histogram is actually just a label.
Question 2
If I were to put all the pieces of information together: is it acurate to say that for displaying grouped discrete(or undgrouped discrete) data on a histograms, we do not need to "pin-point" the precise interval (like in picture A and B),unless asked for, but instead its sufficient just to label the range of discrete values covered(like in C)?

The statement "histograms are not appropriate for continuous data" is not universal--- for a counterexample see https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/edu/power-pouvoir/ch9/histo/5214822-eng.htm. The more proper distinction is that histograms are not appropriate for categorical variables, such as color.

@Semiclassical , thank you for your reply. I looked at the link you sent me and when I checked "Data table for Chart 5.7.1" I saw that the first interval was given as "0-10" and the others, for example the next one "11-20". Did they make a mistake(should it be 1-10)? Because the first category covers 10k, while the following covers only 9k . On the histogram, the first interval is 0 <=x<=10, (need to include the "0") while the others are 10<x<=20, 20<x<=30, etc...
